# Barcode Scanner - Serial Port

Tags: c#, serial-port, barcode-scanner

So, I'm trying to use my Barcode Scanner as a 'Serial' device as opposed to a Keyboard emulator but it is not creating the com port. I have scanned the set-up codes from the manual that set it as a Serial device, that seems to configure the scanner correctly (it stops sending scanned codes to text-box\text editor) but because there is no COM port, I cannot capture the data when I scan a barcode......

Windows installed the driver when it was first plugged in, there wasn't a disk\driver supplied... wondered if anyone else has experienced the same issue.....

Here is my code....

```
class Program
{
    // Create the serial port with basic settings
    private SerialPort port = new SerialPort("com1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program();
    }

    private Program()
    {

        string[] ports = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        Console.WriteLine("Incoming Data:");

        // Attach a method to be called when there
        // is data waiting in the port's buffer
        port.DataReceived += new
          SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

        // Begin communications
        port.Open();

        // Enter an application loop to keep this thread alive
        Application.Run();
    }

    private void port_DataReceived(object sender,
      SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
        Console.WriteLine(port.ReadExisting());
    }
}
```

I get the error message..... 'The port 'com1' does not exist'..... when I try to open the Port.

When I create a virtual Port (using 3rd party app) the code runs BUT I still don't get the data from the Scanner....

Comment: You have to write a block of code to connect to COM port, the scanner will not work for you without explicitly connecting to it by specifying port, baud rates, data bits and few other parameters. It is different from capturing data than in keyboard mode.

Comment: @mauro21pl Yeah, did that, have added my code, i get the error message..... 'The port 'com1' does not exist'..... when i try to open the Port. maybe i'm doing something wrong....

Comment: That would be "COM1", not "com1" ? Can't remember if it was case sensitive as in DOS days... Just debug values in your `ports`.

Comment: @Mikko Viitala Same error... 'The port 'COM1' does not exist.' on 'port.Open();' line…. Scanner is plugged into USB, I would have expected it to create a COMn port and that would be seen in the Device Manager... but its not...

Comment: Once you plug the scanner into USB port, it is plug and play, it should install and initialize the scanner, and create a COM port that you should be able to see in Device Manager. If you dont see it, try to plug the device in into another USB port, that might resolve your issue. Once the scanner is accessible within the Device Manager, it is the starting point on the actual app

Comment: @mauro21pl That's what I would have expected, but no.... tried it on another computer (windows 8 instead of 7) same thing, installs a driver (Generic Microsoft driver from the internet) but still no com port is created... wonder if it could be the cable? Or maybe I need an SDK\API... cant believe that no one else has had this issue, none of the Scanners I see for sale come with a driver disk, so there must be a standard method to connect to them as a serial device (rather than as a Keyboard Widget)....

Comment: That's right, you are connecting with serial cable. That will not work, you will have to purchase an adapter serial to USB, and that will resolve the recognizing your scanner issue. Remember, when you plug into serial port, it is not USB port. Adapter will do the appropriate conversion.

Comment: @mauro21pl It is a USB cable already (came with the scanner, RJ45 into the scanner to USB), I wonder if is is correctly wired for serial coms though....

Comment: Not sure then, google it, or go into documentation, you should find more information reg your scanner, but before the code to work, the computer has to see it, good luck

Comment: @mauro21pl Been googleing for three days already... Thanks for your help tho...

Comment: You probably need to install drivers.  Check the vendor website for drivers, install them then when you plug in your usb device with the scanner on the other end powered up, it should show up in the device manager.  You don't want to install the generic microsoft drivers, those are almost always wrong.

Comment: @Baddack vendor website?!? LOL... if there was one... no web site and the name on the Scanner is 'QCXEON'.... cant find anything.... here is a link https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01CE5SRJO/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: I know that Microsoft has a generic driver/api for these kind of peripherals, I did use it in the past but I don't remember the name. Not sure if is this, but have a look => https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner

Comment: Sorry I dont have an answer to your question but I read that new devices are not supporting serial interface but rather USB or Bluetooth, so I was wondering why are you trying to solve it using serial?  Also, why is keyboard emulation bad, it is an input device like keyboard, why not just look at the TextChanged even on input field when you scan a barcode and determine what to do with it?  I am trying to understand since I work on project to add support for external barcode scanners to our cross-platform mobile app in Xamarin Forms

Answer (score 2):

I just newbie, and I was having task - recieve data from BarCode scaner by serial port... I spent a lot of time... and I have next result

```
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Timers;

namespace BarCode_manager
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private static SerialPort currentPort = new SerialPort();
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        private delegate void updateDelegate(string txt);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            currentPort.PortName = "COM6";
            currentPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            currentPort.ReadTimeout = 1000;

            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
           if (!currentPort.IsOpen)
            {
                currentPort.Open();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); /// for recieve all data from scaner to buffer
                currentPort.DiscardInBuffer();      /// clear buffer          
            }
            try
            {
                string strFromPort = currentPort.ReadExisting();
                lblPortData.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new updateDelegate(updateTextBox), strFromPort);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void updateTextBox(string txt)
        {
            if (txt.Length != 0)
            {
                aTimer.Stop();
                aTimer.Dispose();
                txtReceive.Text = Convert.ToString(aTimer.Enabled);
                currentPort.Close();
            }
            lblPortData.Text = txt;
            lblCount.Content = txt.Length;
            txtReceive.Text = Convert.ToString(aTimer.Enabled);
        }          

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentPort.IsOpen)
                currentPort.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may used below code. I can able to open the COM which I configured in specific port.
SerialPort _serialPort;

```
    // delegate is used to write to a UI control from a non-UI thread
    private delegate void SetTextDeleg(string text);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // all of the options for a serial device
        // can be sent through the constructor of the SerialPort class
        // PortName = "COM1", Baud Rate = 19200, Parity = None, 
        // Data Bits = 8, Stop Bits = One, Handshake = None
        //_serialPort = new SerialPort("COM8", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM8", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
        _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort.Open();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of writing my own barcode scripts.  My scanner defaults to being a plug-n-play USB-HID...Human Interface Device...as opposed to being a USB-COMn port.  I have to scan a barcode to switch it over to serial port mode.  You can watch the transformation process in the Device Manager tree...as a "Ports" branch sprouts out, containing your barcode scanner's details.  Mine's COM3.

Comment: It only helps to know that plug-n-play setup does NOT guarantee you'll see COM Ports...when the default setup is as an HID.  I'm curious.  Now I can open the COM Port...but I'm not getting any data rec'd.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to install dedicated virtual COM Driver for USB barcode scanner. For example on this website ([hdwr.pl](https://hdwr.pl/pl/p/Automatyczny-skaner-kodow-kreskowych-z-podstawka-HDWR-HD29A/118)) you can download it.